# how np.all works with axis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I've tried to use np.all to translate arrays. but the results seems not worked as i expected.

```
x = np.array([[
        [0, 255, 0],
        [255, 0, 255]],
       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 255, 0]],
       [[0, 0, 0],
        [0, 0, 0]]
])
label = np.array([255, 0, 0])
ret = np.all(x == label, axis=0)
print(ret)
```

results:

```
[[False False  True]
 [False False False]]
```

expected:

```
[[False True False]
 [True False True ]]
```

As i think, compare array at dimension 0, should works as this:

```
x[:,0,0] == [255, 0, 0], x[:,0,1] == [255, 0, 0], x[:,0,2] == [255, 0, 0]
x[:,1,0] == [255, 0, 0], x[:,1,1] == [255, 0, 0], x[:,1,2] == [255, 0, 0]
```

but the result seems not working so. Most curiously is that if i change dimension to 1

```
ret = np.all(x == label, axis=1)
```

I've also got a result like this:

```
[[False False False]
 [False False  True]
 [False  True  True]]
```

the variable x's dimension 1 has a size of 2, how can it compared with an array which size is 3 and got a True result!

Comment: I think the confusion comes from the fact that `x == label` compares on a different axis from what you expect. You could try `np.all(x == label[:,None,None], axis=0)`.

Comment: The `axis` parameter is for `np.all`, not for the `==` operation. Perhaps start with 1D then 2D arrays and print intermediate arrays to see what is happening.

Comment: Oh, that's really help! I misunderstand axis work with == operation... That really confused me about what it output.  hilberts_drinking_problem Your solution works as what i want.   Michael Szczesny, Thanks for correcting my misunderstand.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`x` is (3,2,3), `label` is (3,)

`x == label` broadcasts `label` to (1,1,3)

The `all` reduces the first axis leaving (2,3)

So the test is `x[0,0,:] == [255, 0, 0]` etc